# Resolving power of microscope

Tags: optics, microscopy

Can anyone explain me the derivation part as given in the image ?
[image]

[image]

According to Rayleigh Criterion, the angle subtended of the radius of the airy disc is given by 1.22 λ / D

D = diameter or aperture of the lens.

In the image they have considered  θ = 1.22 λ / D , if i think according to Rayleigh's criterion it should be  θ/2 = 1.22 λ / D. (According to Rayleigh Criterion we consider the angle equivalent to the radius, and not the diameter of the airy disc).

I don't understand why they have considered that ?

Please help.

Comment: Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but type it out instead so it is readable by all users and so it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 1):

An *Airy disk* having a having a central spot in the focal plane the ***radius*** of the first zero is
$$d = 1.22f\frac{\lambda}{D}$$

In the object space the angular resolution is then
$$\theta = 1.22\frac{\lambda}{D}$$

where $D$ is the ***diameter*** of the aperture

You should check your definition once again.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction#Circular_aperture